# Python, Fabric, Windows command line adds weird ^@ (caret-at) symbols during input

Tags: python, windows, cmd, fabric

I have a remote Ubuntu server VPS, which I connect and do commands via fabric.

I using Windows PC to connect to this remote VPS, with this commands:

```
@task
def git_pull():
    """
    """
    run("cd ~/{}/; git pull".format(env.repo_name))
```

When I run this command, it promts me to write my Git's login and  password.

When I try to input them it writes them like this:

```
(virtualenv) D:\path\to\project\fabfile>fab common.git_pull
[1.2.3.4] Executing task 'common.git_pull'
[1.2.3.4] run: cd ~/project/; git pull
[1.2.3.4] out: Username for 'https://git.example.com': u^@s^@e^@r^@
```

As you can see when I try to write `user` it writes it as `u^@s^@e^@r^@`

It appends this weird caret-at `^@`symbols

Why windows fabric appends these weird `^@` symbols?

Is it because of `paramiko` which is being used by fabric?

I thought this happening because of different encodings and I used `chcp` command and it still appends these extra symbols.

Comment: `^@` is displayed for a __NULL__ character, i.e. there is a null byte appended after each letter. It looks like the string `user` is not send ASCII encoded as four bytes with the hexadecimal values `75 73 65 72`, but UTF-16 encoded with eight bytes with the hexadecimal values `75 00 73 00 65 00 72 00`. Or the four letters are sent one after the other as four null terminated strings.

Comment: @Mofi is this windows' cmd issue?

Comment: I don't have your environment with Python on a machine running with Ubuntu connected from a Windows PC using a VPS channel and Fabric. So I can't help more. Windows cmd uses usually a single byte per character text encoding with an OEM code page according to country configured for the user account. I think the issue is caused by the data transfer between Ubuntu server and Windows client and not by Windows cmd itself. Windows cmd can be started with `/U` for Unicode (UTF-16) output into file or a pipe as used here. But `/U` is not used by default on starting `cmd.exe`.

Comment: You could use free Sysinternals [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out what exactly is going on here. The command line used to start `cmd.exe` can be seen with Process Monitor by right clicking on process `cmd.exe` in log, clicking in context menu on __Properties__ and looking on tab __Process__ on the __Command Line__.

Comment: Windows PowerShell uses UTF16LE character encoding for its output by default.  You might need to configure Fabric to use that encoding.